# Looking for a book on hiking trails in USA written by an African American woman

Tags: hiking

Some time ago, I think less than three years ago, I read an article about a long network of hiking trails in the United States. It may have been the Appalachian Trail but I may be wrong.

This article may be on atlasobscura.com but after a long search I could not find it.

This article also talked about an African American woman who had done the trail and had written a book about her experiences, the sport being a mostly white world as she described it.

I am doing a study on travel literature in which the traveler is external to the ethnicity and customs of the territory he or she travels and describes this territory through foreign eyes, such as the classic works of Goethe in Italy or the British travelers in Europe and Asia in the 19th and 20th centuries. I am curious to know if this particular book can be included in this type of travel books.

Can anyone help me to find it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because while the book may be about travel, the question isn't. [Literature.se](https://literature.stackexchange.com/) *might* be a better fit (but do check the help section first, I'm not a regular there and don't know exactly what kind of questions they accept).

Comment: After a long search? My first search hit for "Appalachian Trail African American woman" brought up **Rahawa Haile**. Here is the [Atlas Obscura article](https://www.atlasobscura.com/articles/exit-interview-i-was-a-black-female-thru-hiker-on-the-appalachian-trail).

Comment: @WeatherVane Oh, my goodness. I was afraid something like this was going to happen to my eternal shame. I'm being especially obtuse these days. Thank you so much.

Comment: Don't know if (white female) Cheryl Strayed's 2012 memoir [Wild: From Lost to Found on the Pacific Crest Trail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wild_(memoir)) will be of interest to you. It was made into a film with Reece Witherspoon.

Comment: @ChrisH No problem for me if you close now that I have the info I looked for. I dont know too well the culture of this particular stackexchange community so take my point of view with a grain of salt but I think that asking for the identification of a travel guide would be on topic even if you are not going to use it for travel. Literature looks a bit too "high culture".

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you very much for the suggestion Cheryl Strayed. I will make a note of it.

Comment: @ChrisH Some on this site would argue that one could read this book while traveling, and thus be on topic ;-) I wouldn't go that far myself though.

Comment: @Berend that would sound like [boat programming](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14470/what-is-the-boat-programming-meme-about) to me ;)

Comment: @ChrisH Yes, I forgot about that ;-) Travel.SE seems to have a tendency towards boat programming